# How do you implement an encapsulated serialization in C++ without a macro?

Tags: c++, serialization, macros

I am wondering about this. I was trying to write a C++ class to serialize a polymorphic object. That is, I have a

```
template<class T>
class PolymorphicSerializable {
   ...
};
```

which can be CRTP-inherited from the root of a serializable polymorphic hierarchy (that is, "T" becomes that root class). It contains a "static" member variable that is a map of class names to factory functions or function objects that can construct new instances of whatever derived class was saved, when loading (the name of the class is saved along with the data).

However the problem I have is this static member must, of course, be initialized. The way I'm doing this right now is to use some macros to fill out this boilerplate. The problem, however, is that to initialize that static we of course need the template parameter, and if "T" is a *template instance* (i.e. root class is a template instance) I run into something like

```
MACRO_FOR_INITIALIZING_STATIC_MEMBER(SomeClass<int, int>)
```

(not its actual name) and the C++ preprocessor doesn't like this because of the comma. Putting

```
MACRO_FOR_INITIALIZING_STATIC_MEMBER((SomeClass<int, int>))
```

doesn't work either because a template argument (i.e. "T" of PolymorphicSerializable) cannot be enclosed in parentheses and that parenthesized version is what ends up as the template argument.

What can be done about this? There needs to be some way to encapsulate away that implementation detail of the class map -- but how? Is there even a way to do it without a macro?

Comment: It may interest you to know about the existence of 'variadic macros' (C++11), which may solve that particular problem:  `#define MACRO(...) doStuff(__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from variadic macros, as suggested by a comment to your question, you could wrap the static member in a getter function, as it removes the requirment of allocating space for the static member separately:

```
template<class T>
class PolymorphicSerializable {
   typedef SomeType<T> StaticInstanceType;
   static StaticInstanceType& getContext() {
       static StaticInstanceType instance;
       return instance;
   }
};
```

And use that getter everywhere.